# Everytime I run rake assets:precompile fonts don't load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, fonts, asset-pipeline

I'm super frustrated, my main issue with rails is the asset pipeline. Yesterday I had everything working fine in production mode but today I made a change to one of my forms by adding

```
:class => "classname"
```

to one of the fields

now in the field itself it's displaying code and even if I remove that field, the page is stuck somehow in cache but I ran

```
 rake tmp:cache:clear
```

and nothing worked so I delete the public/assets folder and ran

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

and now the fonts arent loading

what could have happened to just suddenly make things not work with such a minor change?
I don't get it and rails is p*ssing me off I don't know why why why, somebody please explain this to me

this all worked just a few hours ago

config/application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/assets/fonts"
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/assets/images"
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
 config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )

config.assets.precompile += ["ss-standard/ss-standard.ttf",
                     "ss-standard/ss-standard.eot",
                     "ss-standard/ss-standard.svg",
                     "ss-standard/ss-standard.woff"]
```

the fonts load in chrome but not on internet explorer or firefox, neither do the images

Comment: why don't they load? For example is the server 404ing (or other error) when the browser tries to load the font files

Comment: html error in text_field_tag had to add , nil, :class => etc.. but the fonts load only in google chrome, firefox just uses regular font and doesn't load images either but it all works on chrome